# Использовать PHPExcel или header() для сохранения таблицы в файл Excel

Tags: php

Как скачать данные, выведенные в таблицу, из MySQL в файл Excel?

При помощи `header()`, чтобы выводилось окно запроса на сохранение в файл или при помощи PHPExcel.

Comment: красные глаза не есть оправдание, напишите, что Вы пробовали сделать, в чем именно Вы видите проблему, вставьте пример кода где Вы наблюдаете проблему.

Comment: Так вот именно не могу начать. Не знаю, что куда ставить. Но сейчас работаю с header(). Сохраняет файл, но не читает заголовок столбца и кириллицу.

Comment: 3 ссылка из [google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=PHPExcel&oq=PHPExcel&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.1047j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=php%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20excel)  - http://habrahabr.ru/post/245233/ примеров по phpexcel действительно много, в т.ч. числе есть и офф документация.

Answer (score 1):

Вот сделал с помощью header, теперь буду приписывать это к кнопке. Чтобы сохранял только по нажатию кнопки. Недостаток не читает название столбцов на кириллице и при открытии файла выдает предупреждение. Ещё буду работать над этим. И попробую PHPExcel.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".date("d-m-Y")."-export.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Спасибо за приведенные примеры.